# "Popular Items" web part causing Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:

Tags: 2013, web-part, migration, ajax

We have recently migrated from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. In our site we have the registration control with ajax update panel which is working fine in all the pages other than home. After analysis, I found that this issue is happening only if the popular items web part exists (which comes under "search-driven content" category). The issue occurs whenever I attempt to do a partial postback. I'm not getting anything changed and instead I'm seeing an error in the browser console. Please find the error details below:

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Mon, 2 Dec 2013 07:18:16 UTC


    Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
    Details: Error parsing near 'ebPartEditing|false|<script type='text/j'.
    Line: 5
    Char: 84289
    Code: 0
    URI: http://collabsl-sp13:2009/ScriptResource.axd?d=0rRB-yfZVL04qQ_sBVXlxTsUw5u9OHe5YGiFPW7cz73oBgBM0PAqMA1ULIykAQQ0g_Mpuyar0vF8-YdXty6YKhCwlSkExCy5lL6BpWJP5aWwlnnNwwYwbnef_M3lQnUZTz3aZOX6_ZLHnKx8sj-WEFZIgFNn98eMj4iT12A79mqAeKTY_IT9SxyYT5guU-i30&t=6119e399
```

I have my update panel code as below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel class="something" ID="something" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
                        ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="something" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <img id="something" alt="Captcha Image" title="Captcha Image"
                                runat="server" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In my code behind, what am i trying is, to refresh the captcha image which involves assigning the .aspx url to the image. The assigned .aspx image have the logic for writing back the new image.

I have tried changing the IIS settings with respect to idle time and framework type(integrated/classic)..

Comment: @Benny Skogberg Oh ok.. any how, any idea to attract the experts here?

Comment: Yes. Add a bounty to the question, and it gets highlighted in the feature tab on the start page. Good luck!

Comment: @Benny Skogberg If i don't have enough reputation points? and yes i don't have!!

Comment: Well, then you have to get more reputation points by helping others, and gain reps before you can use them.

Comment: @Benny Skogberg :) im working on it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the loading behaviour option in the popular content web part. 
Changing the default "Sync" to "Asyn" under the settings did the job.
[Reference URL](http://devspoint.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/sql-report-viewer-web-part-issue/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650218.aspx

> In Visual Studio, add a reference to
>   Microsoft.Practices.SPG.AJAXSupport.dll. Add a SafeScriptManager
>   control to your page and set the EnableUpdatePanelSupport flag to
>   true. This changes the postback script that is needed for the
>   UpdatePanel control to work in a SharePoint environment.

Example code:

```
<%@ Register 
   Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.SPG.AJAXSupport, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8768CCAE1C3C9EB2"
   TagPrefix="spg" 
   Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.SPG.AJAXSupport.Controls" %>

<spg:SafeScriptManager ID="SafeScriptManager" 
                                                   runat="server" 
          EnableUpdatePanelSupport = “True”
                                                   />

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="Server" id="MyUpdatePanel">
 ...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: i tried to add this reference before, but i couldn't get actual dll from online before :(.. do you know any exact place where i can get this dll?